# Cast Color Name to SolidColorBrush

Tags: c#, wpf

How I can **cast** *color name* to `SolidColorBrush` type? I mean the word i.e. "Yellow".

```
SolidColorBrush scb =  ??? ; // "Yellow"
```

Thank you!

Comment: I would simply [_construct_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558629.aspx) a `SolidColorBrush` from a `Color`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For getting the color, use:

```
Color col=(Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red");
```

Then create your brush:

```
Brush brush=new SolidColorBrush(col);
```

or if you can use the Colors-enum

```
Brush brush=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: This is perfect in WPF, but not working in Windows Phone 8, how to do this in WP8

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827964/how-to-convert-a-string-into-a-color-for-windows-phone-c-sharp

Answer (score 14):

If you already know the name of the color you can get the brush directly from [`Brushes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.aspx):

```
SolidColorBrush scb = Brushes.Yellow; //scb seems a bit redundant at this point...
```

In code you should usually *not* use converters unless you have a string whose value you do not know.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot *cast* one to another. They are simply different concepts. A brush is brush and color is, well, a color. Just because a brush "paints" in a specific color, doesn't mean you can interchange one with another.

You can however create a [SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558629.aspx) with a specific color, for example:

```
 var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Yellow);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// Yellow is green + red
SolidColorBrush yellowBrush = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 0));
```